# Pivot_wider - Error : Can't convert <double> to <list>

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` which lists relative frequencies of different species in multiple stations.

I tried using `pivot_wider to be able to transform it into a matrix and use decostand to have the hellinger distance, but an error appears when I use` pivot_wider` and I don't know how to fix it. I already searched on google but I still have the problem. Here is the code.

```
> chalut_lg<-freq_chfr%>%
+   group_by(station)%>%
+   select(station,espece,freq_rel) #espece=species and freq_rel=frequencies by station
> chalut_lg
# A tibble: 84 x 3
# Groups:   station [9]
   station espece                           freq_rel
   <chr>   <chr>                               <dbl>
 1 EM15    "Actiniaria sp. "                 0.0435 
 2 EM15    "Chionoecetes opilio"             0.130  
 3 EM15    "Lycodes sp."                     0.0435 
 4 EM15    "Meganyctiphanes norvegica"       0.0435 
 5 EM15    "Pandalus borealis"               0.652  
 6 EM15    "Pseudopleuronectes americanus"   0.0870 
 7 EM16    "Actiniaria sp. "                 0.00259
 8 EM16    "Aspidophoroides monopterygius "  0.0298 
 9 EM16    "Chionoecetes opilio"             0.0595 
10 EM16    "Crevette sp."                    0.00776
# ... with 74 more rows
> chalut_large<-chalut_lg%>%
+   pivot_wider(names_from=espece,
+               values_from=freq_rel,
+               values_fill=0)
Erreur : Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
De plus : Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

When I use `values_fn=list` in `pivot_wider`, the second error disappear but the first one is still there.

```
> chalut_large<-chalut_lg%>%
+   pivot_wider(names_from=espece,
+               values_from=freq_rel,
+               values_fill=0,
+               values_fn=list)
Erreur : Can't convert <double> to <list>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: could you to do ```dput(chalut_lg[1:10,])``` and post the result here?

Comment: I think the error message tells the story, you have duplicates in the espece column.  You need to make those unique, possibly by using them in conjunction with the station variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's works from me.

```
chalub_lg <- tibble(station = c(rep("EM15", 6), rep("EM16", 4)),
                    espece = c("Actiniaria sp. ", "Chionoecetes opilio", "Lycodes sp.",
                               "Meganyctiphanes norvegica", "Pandalus borealis",
                               "Pseudopleuronectes americanus", "Actiniaria sp. ",
                               "Aspidophoroides monopterygius ", "Chionoecetes opilio",
                               "Crevette sp."),
                    freq_rel = c(0.0435, 0.130, 0.0435, 0.0435, 0.652, 0.0870,
                                0.00259, 0.0298, 0.0595, 0.00776))

library(vegan)

chalub_lg %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = espece,
              values_from = freq_rel,
              values_fill = 0) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "station") %>%
  decostand(method = "hellinger", MARGIN = 1)
```

The argument `MARGIN = 1` in decostand() function indicates that hellinger distance was calculated by row, if you want calculated by column you must to use `MARGIN = 2`